# Decimal zero padding

Tags: python

I need to output decimal numbers in a price format,

i.e.

10   = 10.00
11.1 = 11.10

How can I achieve this using decimal.Decimal class ?

```
pad_zero(Decimal('10.0'))
>>>Decimal('10.00')
```

**EDIT:**format method does not fit my need because I need to pass it on as decimal, I understand though, that i can convert it back to afterwards, but such to-and-fro seems somewhat unpythonic.

Comment: Look at the string `format()` method and then close this question.  http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Comment: And after that I am supposed to die of embarrassment ?

Comment: Not die of embarrassment. Fix the question to show what you've read and why the `format()` method doesn't fit your needs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this :

```
Decimal('10.0').quantize(Decimal('1.00'))
```

Comment: thanx for the most simple solution

Comment: `Decimal('1e26').quantize(Decimal('1.00'))` raises InvalidOperation though I doubt that it affects the OP case.

Answer (score 3):

For currency calculations, I prefer this.

```
>>> penny=Decimal('0.01')
>>> Decimal('10').quantize(penny)
Decimal('10.00')
```

It's wordy but explicit.

For currency formatting, I use `format()`.

Comment: for those of you that are newer to code, wordy isn't necessarily bad - especially in my case.  wordy means it's easy to read.  easy to read means i'm not stuck maintaining it!

Answer (score 2):

There's a good example of how to format Decimal objects as a "money formatted string" in the [Python documentation for the decimal module](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#recipes).

I'm a little surprised at how awkward it is -- usually formatting in Python is fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

I would follow the `moneyfmt` recipe in the [Python Decimal documentation Recipes section](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#recipes).

This recipe creates a function that takes a decimal value and returns a string formatted as a currency.

```
>>> d = Decimal('10.0')
>>> moneyfmt(d, curr='$')
'$10.00'
```

Below is the actual code, copied sans examples from the Decimal Recipe documentation:

```
def moneyfmt(value, places=2, curr='', sep=',', dp='.',
             pos='', neg='-', trailneg=''):
    """Convert Decimal to a money formatted string.

    places:  required number of places after the decimal point
    curr:    optional currency symbol before the sign (may be blank)
    sep:     optional grouping separator (comma, period, space, or blank)
    dp:      decimal point indicator (comma or period)
             only specify as blank when places is zero
    pos:     optional sign for positive numbers: '+', space or blank
    neg:     optional sign for negative numbers: '-', '(', space or blank
    trailneg:optional trailing minus indicator:  '-', ')', space or blank

    """
    q = Decimal(10) ** -places      # 2 places --> '0.01'
    sign, digits, exp = value.quantize(q).as_tuple()
    result = []
    digits = map(str, digits)
    build, next = result.append, digits.pop
    if sign:
        build(trailneg)
    for i in range(places):
        build(next() if digits else '0')
    build(dp)
    if not digits:
        build('0')
    i = 0
    while digits:
        build(next())
        i += 1
        if i == 3 and digits:
            i = 0
            build(sep)
    build(curr)
    build(neg if sign else pos)
    return ''.join(reversed(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be quite simple like this (if you don't use decimal.Decimal class as suggested by [S. Lott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10661/s-lott)) :

```
    >>> decimal_fmt = "{:.2f}"   
    >>> x = 10
    >>> print(decimal_fmt.format(x))
    10.00
    >>> x = 11.1
    >>> print(decimal_fmt.format(x))
    11.10
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the precision for your context before you create your instance:

```
>>> getcontext().prec = 2
```

Comment: Nothing.  Do that before you create an numbers.  Try it.

Comment: if doesnt work for me:    `>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 2  
>> d = decimal.Decimal('10.0')  
>> d  
Decimal('10.0')`

Comment: it seems that the context give you n decimal places only in you define your decimal number with these places already filled: (Decimal('10.00000')) but you dont get aditional zeros if you do Decimal('10.0')

Comment: @joaquin - true, and as @S.Lott has pointed out, formatting (right-padding) is a function of "strings", not numeric types.

Answer (score 0):

Use locale `currency`. It works flawlessly with the Decimal class.

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '') # this sets locale to the current Operating System value
print(locale.currency(Decimal('1346896.67544'), grouping=True, symbol=True))
```

will output in my Windows 10 configured to *Brazilian Portuguese*:

```
R$ 1.346.896,68
```

It is somewhat verbose, so if you will use it a lot, maybe it is better to predefine some parameters and have a shorter name and use it inside a f-string:

```
fmt = lambda x: locale.currency(x, grouping=True, symbol=True)
print(f"Value: {fmt(1346896.67444)}"
```

It works with `Decimal` and `float`. You can configure to symbol to `False` if it isn't necessary.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using `Decimal('10.0')` you could use `float('10.0')` which will produce the effect you require.

**Edit:** Realised that you were looking to represent it with 2 decimal places. In this case, there's a good example in the Python docs for converting a `Decimal()` object to money: http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#recipes

Comment: I can't print it directly:
str(float('10.0'))
>>>10.0

Comment: It won't work at all.  It doesn't include two decimal places except under rare circumstances.

Comment: @KushaIP: Since the OP wants a price format, we know these numbers represent a currency. In which case, the OP is not going to want to use float, but instead will want to use decimal. http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html